# i am trying to deploy my smart contract using hardhat but when I am trying to deploy my deploy.js file I face error like that

Tags: deployment, hardhat

I am trying to deploy my smart contract using hardhat technology but I found error

```
PS C:\Users\shail\Desktop\Gdrive 3.0> npx hardhat run --network localhost scripts/deploy.js
TypeError: (0 , ethers_1.getAddress) is not a function
    at new HardhatEthersSigner (C:\Users\shail\Desktop\Gdrive 3.0\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\signers.ts:73:30)
    at Function.create (C:\Users\shail\Desktop\Gdrive 3.0\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\signers.ts:65:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at getSigner (C:\Users\shail\Desktop\Gdrive 3.0\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\helpers.ts:60:29)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at getSigners (C:\Users\shail\Desktop\Gdrive 3.0\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\helpers.ts:45:30)
```

```
your text
```

Comment: my deploy.js file is const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const Upload = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Upload");
  const upload = await Upload.deploy();

  await upload.deployed();

  console.log("Library deployed to:", upload.address);
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});